# EXC_BAD_ACCESS in UITextField while typing

Tags: iphone, xcode, uitextfield, exc-bad-access

I created a brand new view-based project and added into the viewDidLoad

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    myField = [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(50, 50, 150, 31)];
    myField.delegate=self;
    [self.view addSubview:myField];
    [myField release];
}
```

my header file is

```
@interface textfieldpracticeViewController : UIViewController<UITextFieldDelegate>{
UITextField *myField;
}
```

when i click in the textfield and the keyboard pops up, i start typing but on the 2nd character, i get the exc_bad_access error.  I ran it with NSZombieEnabled, NSDebugEnabled, MallocStackLoggin, and MallocStackNoCompact but they weren't able to catch the error.

This fails when using the iphone 4.3 simulator, but works fine when i build it on my iphone.  is this an xcode error or am i missing something?

Thanks

P.S. even tried property/synthesize out of desparation

Comment: Why not use IB? The setup is easier, and these problems never occur. (At least they don't for me.)

Comment: hm that's odd, IB doesn't work for me neither.  I removed the extra stuff from my .h and .m files but still same problem. I kept the `<UITextFieldDelegate` in my .h and hooked up the textfield delegate to the fileowner in the IB

Comment: If you set up your textfield in IB, you do not need to alloc init your textfield in your .m file. Also, don't forget to implement the necessary methods for being a textfieldDelegate.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Try disabling autocorrection in the simulator's keyboard settings. This seems to be a bug in the autocorrection system of the simulator's iOS.

Comment: Wow, just wasted a lot of time on this with my UITextView. Thanks for the solution!

Comment: This seems to be fixed in the 5.0 simulator in Xcode 4.2.  It still crashes in the 4.2 simulator in Xcode 4.2.

Comment: Holy cows, that's it!  I just wasted a good hour on this one myself.  Thank goodness for the internet, and for helpful folks like you!

Comment: This appears to still be an issue in simulator 7.1