# Going Crazy with UITextField Input in a Very Simple App

Tags: objective-c, ios4

I have a PromoCodeViewController which is triggered using the following code:

```
@implementation Demo_WebServiceCallingUsingiOSAppDelegate

@synthesize window = _window,promoCodeController;

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];

    self.promoCodeController = [[PromoCodeViewController alloc] init]; 

    [self.window addSubview:self.promoCodeController.view]; 

    // Override point for customization after application launch.
    self.window.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
    return YES;
}
```

The PromoCodeViewController contains the UITextField and I implement the UITextFieldDelegate for the PromoCodeViewController as shown:

```
@interface PromoCodeViewController : UIViewController<UITextFieldDelegate>

{
    IBOutlet UITextField *promoCodeTextField; 
}

@property (nonatomic,retain) IBOutlet UITextField *promoCodeTextField; 

@end
```

I implement the textFieldShouldReturn method as shown:

```
- (BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField
{
    return TRUE; 
}
```

I have even setup the PromoCodeViewController to be the delegate for the UITextField events. When I start typing in the TextBox it throws "Program received signal. EXC_BAD_ACCESS". It happens when I type second character in the UITextField. What am I doing wrong?

UPDATE 1:

The error comes on the following section:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    @autoreleasepool {
        return UIApplicationMain(argc, argv, nil, NSStringFromClass([Demo_WebServiceCallingUsingiOSAppDelegate class]));
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't think you should be setting your window to you promoCodeViewController in the first code block... Though I don't think that is what is causing your error.

Comment: what is the stack trace at the moment of the crash?

Comment: @sergio There is nothing in the stacktrace!

Comment: See my [answer here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6990419/exc-bad-access-in-uitextfield-while-typing/6990882#6990882). I had the same problem once and it seems to be related to a bug in the simulator SDK.

Comment: The EXC_BAD_ACCESS errors as far as I know are caused by trying to access something that no longer exists, IE wasn't retained enough, or was released early. It doesn't look like the code you posted has anything like that wrong, so it must be elsewhere. Are you detecting text being typed anywhere in your code? Try placing some breakpoints, or NSLog messages for yourself, and post the results.

Comment: It's likely the simulator bug as posted above. I had the same issue - really annoying and not obvious at all.

Comment: @omz, Yes you are right! I turned off all the keyboard things on the simulator and it started working again. If you can post your comment as answer then I can accept it. Thanks!

Comment: What's your evidence for the existence of a Simulator bug, and if there is one, what specifically is the bug, and in what way is it relevant to the OP's problem?

Comment: I can't reproduce the problem now (might have to do with SDK version), but when I had it, I tried to debug it with `NSZombieEnabled` and the message to a deallocated object was sent deep down in some framework classes that seemed autocorrection-related. The problem never occured on an actual device, only in the simulator and even in minimal test projects. After disabling autocorrection in the simulator's keyboard settings, the crash disappeared. As I said, it never happened on an actual device, even though I always have autocorrection enabled there.

Answer (score 0):

It looks as though you're missing an `@synthesize` statement for the `promoCodeTextField` property. Add the following to your `Demo_WebServiceCallingUsingiOSAppDelegate` class (which by the way, might benefit from renaming):

```
@synthesize promoCodeTextField = _promoCodeTextField;
```

Without the `@synthesize` statement, Xcode's Nib File Editor will directly set the instance variable instead of calling the accessor methods (since they don't exist); as a consequence the text field is never retained.

Comment: I have synthesize! It is a BUG in the simulator!

Comment: There's no `@synthesize` statement for `promoCodeTextField` in the code you posted.

Comment: It's true that the `promoCodeTextField` isn't synthesized. That can't be the problem here however. First, the outlet is declared directly on the instance variable, so the nib-loading mechanism will use `setValue:forKey:` which can fall back to accessing the variable directly if there's no setter. In this case, the [documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Protocols/NSKeyValueCoding_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html) states that the value will be retained. Even if that was not the case, the containing view would retain the text field.

Answer (score 0):

What object is the delegate of the textfield? Objects do not usually retain their delegates (since the delegate is often retaining a reference to the object, and retain-cycles lead to memory leaks).

My hunch is that your text field's delegate is defined and attached in your nib, but isn't being retained anywhere, so shortly after the nib is loaded the delegate is deallocated. As soon as the text field attempts to do anything with the delegate, it crashes.

If so, make sure something (usually the application delegate) is retaining a reference to whatever object is serving as the delegate of your text field.