# UITextField delegate jumping to 100% CPU usage and crashing upon using keyboard shortcut

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, uitextfield, uitextfielddelegate

So, I have a `UITextField` subclass which is it's own `Delegate` and is crashing when keyboard shortcuts are used. It maxes out on `CPU` and doesn't give an error. Without assigning itself as it's `Delegate`, it works without problem. When it is assigned as it's `Delegate`, it crashes even when using none of the (optional) methods.

Try it yourself:

Subclass `UITextField`.

```
- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame
{
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
    if (self) {

        self.delegate = self;

    }
    return self;
}
```

It should crash.

**EDIT**
Backtrace:

```
* thread #1: tid = 0x3bb8d, 0x39f14726 libobjc.A.dylib`lookUpImpOrNil + 18, queue = 'com.apple.main-thread, stop reason = signal SIGSTOP
    frame #0: 0x39f14726 libobjc.A.dylib`lookUpImpOrNil + 18
    frame #1: 0x39f0dcb6 libobjc.A.dylib`class_respondsToSelector + 34
    frame #2: 0x39f1d05c libobjc.A.dylib`-[NSObject respondsToSelector:] + 32
    frame #3: 0x323b9242 UIKit`-[UITextField respondsToSelector:] + 46
    frame #4: 0x325c88a2 UIKit`-[UITextField customOverlayContainer] + 50
    frame #5: 0x325c8730 UIKit`-[UITextField automaticallySelectedOverlay] + 28
    frame #6: 0x32554208 UIKit`-[UIKeyboardImpl inputOverlayContainer] + 424
    frame #7: 0x32553942 UIKit`-[UIKeyboardImpl _autocorrectPromptRects] + 454
    frame #8: 0x323c7530 UIKit`-[UIKeyboardImpl updateAutocorrectPrompt:] + 368
    frame #9: 0x323e63e0 UIKit`-[UIDelayedAction timerFired:] + 80
    frame #10: 0x305fbe6c Foundation`__NSFireTimer + 64
    frame #11: 0x2fbe1e86 CoreFoundation`__CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_TIMER_CALLBACK_FUNCTION__ + 14
    frame #12: 0x2fbe1aa2 CoreFoundation`__CFRunLoopDoTimer + 794
    frame #13: 0x2fbdfe2a CoreFoundation`__CFRunLoopRun + 1218
    frame #14: 0x2fb4a540 CoreFoundation`CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 524
    frame #15: 0x2fb4a322 CoreFoundation`CFRunLoopRunInMode + 106
    frame #16: 0x348812ea GraphicsServices`GSEventRunModal + 138
    frame #17: 0x324011e4 UIKit`UIApplicationMain + 1136
    frame #18: 0x0009929c Today`main(argc=1, argv=0x27d79c80) + 164 at main.m:29
```

Comment: And the crash is...? Provide details about the error such as the complete error message and details about the stack trace.

Comment: How do you know it crashes, since you apparently have no error messages to report?

Comment: It doesn't give me an error, it just totally stops responding, and XCode says the CPU usage jumped to 100%.

Comment: Use the debugger and see what is happening.

Comment: Probably you have a infinite recursion. Simply pause the app and have a look at the stack frame. Report the content here. (Only the first 10.000 rows, ;-))

Comment: @AminNegm-Awad Posted the backtrace.

Comment: Check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6990419/exc-bad-access-in-uitextfield-while-typing. Setting autocorrection or keyboard type fixes the problem

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Problem *solved* by changing the delegate to the object which inits my text view.

Answer (score 13):

I encountered the same issue today when working with a self-delegating `UITextField` subclass.  If it is not possible to change the delegate to something other than self, I would recommend overriding `respondsToSelector` rather than implementing a `customOverlayContainer` method that may return an invalid object (are you sure it's supposed to be an instance of `UITextField`?  How do you know iOS isn't asking for a `UIView` or a `CGLayer` or any other type of object?)

```
-(BOOL) respondsToSelector:(SEL)aSelector {

    NSString * selectorName = NSStringFromSelector(aSelector);

    if ([selectorName isEqualToString:@"customOverlayContainer"]) {

        NSLog(@"preventing self.delegate == self crash");

        return NO;
    }

    return [super respondsToSelector:aSelector];
}
```

Comment: dave, I definitely owe you. Google search for "customOverlayContainer" leads to this thread, this thread leads to keeping me from going insane. Thank you!

Comment: So, Apple Doc denies calling `-respondsToSelector:` on a `super` - instead you must call something like this:
`return [UITextField instancesRespondToSelector:aSelector];`

Answer (score 1):

I *solved* this by custom customOverlayContainer and return the textFiled. eg.

```
@implementation CustomTextField

- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame {
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
    if (self) {
        self.delegate = self;
    }
    return self;
}

- (id)customOverlayContainer {
    return self;
}

@end
```

Tested on iOS 7 and iOS 6.

Comment: Is "customOverlayContainer" private method? I am not getting any doc for this.